# How to cite an old poem which appears in a new collection/anthology put together by a different editor? (Chicago)

Tags: citations, humanities

According to CMS, we should cite a poem in an anthology as we would a chapter in an edited book. But, what if the poem was orginally written in another year?

eg.

> Hàn Mặc Tử. [1939] 2009.“Hồn là ai?” (My soul, who art thou?). In Hàn
> Mặc Tử. Tác phẩm chọn lọc [Hàn Mặc Tử. Collection of poems] edited by
> Nguyễn Đăng Điệp. Hà Nội: Nhà xuất bản giáo dục Việt Nam.

Is this correct? Putting this way might be confusing to the reader as they might think this collection was reprinted in 2009. The correct understanding should be that this poem was written in 1938 and published in 2009 as part of a collection.

Following this, should the in-text citation for the poem be

1. (Han Mac Tu 1939)
2. (Han Mac Tu 2009)
3. (Nguyễn Đăng Điệp 2009)

Please help!!

Comment: I don't know anything about Chicago, but if you misled the reader into thinking the poem is from 2009, that would be bad. Also *always* cite the original source of *any* information, *and* the oldest version you were able to get you hands on, plus a newer one that might be more accessible to other readers.

Comment: Can't give you an authoritative or complete answer. But you must include a cite of the anthology if you quote text from the anthology. They may have translated, edited, etc. After that, I can't tell you what is correct. @Karl seems to be giving good advice.

Answer (score -1):

If the publisher gives you the option of using BibTeX, here are the BibTeX database entries I've used in an equivalent situation:

> @INCOLLECTION{Newton:1726:PNP, crossref="Motte:1846:NPM",
> author="Isaac Newton", title="Philosophiae Naturalis Principia
> Mathematica", pages="73--507", edition="Third", year=1726,
> note="Translated into {E}nglish by {A}ndrew {M}otte; first edition
> published 1687",
> url="https://archive.org/details/newtonspmathema00newtrich" }
>
> @BOOK{Motte:1846:NPM, editor="Andrew Motte", title="{N}EWTON'S
> PRINCIPIA: THE MATHEMATICAL PRINCIPLES OF NATURAL PHILOSOPHY",
> booktitle="{N}EWTON'S PRINCIPIA: THE MATHEMATICAL PRINCIPLES OF
> NATURAL PHILOSOPHY", publisher="Daniel Adee", year=1846,
> edition="FIRST {A}MERICAN", address="New York",
> url="https://archive.org/details/newtonspmathema00newtrich" }

Then you can let the publisher's BibTeX style file sort out the CMS formatting.